# Spring boot web main/ressources/static not reloading if changed outside STS

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm working on a AngularJS project with Spring Boot and the HTML/JS/CSS are placed inside src/main/ressources/static.

The problem is that if I change these files outside Eclipse and refresh the browser the changes are not reflected. Previously I worked on a project where the HTML/JS/CSS files where placed in src/main/webapp folder and I didn't have this kind problem.

I'm required to keep the files in ressources/static and I also can't use a live reload server to serve the files. I have tried to enable "Refresh using native hooks or polling" in Eclipse, but still sometimes the files take awhile to refresh.

Is there a way to have the same behavior that using src/main/webapp folder gives?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I end up using an workaround which was adding the config below to the pom.xml and runninng the app with `mvn spring-boot:run` instead of Eclipse's "Run as Spring Boot Application"

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <addResources>true</addResources>
            </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly. You want to be able to change files outside of Eclipse and have those changes in server also?

If you change `HTML/JS/CSS` files outside of Eclipse you can sync files to `{source_directory}\target\classes\static` for instance update.

It worked for me when I was using the development server. Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: starcorn is right, check also [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5136) for more details.